# Unexpected T_Variable parse error in PHP

Tags: php

I have this PHP code and getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$e' (T_VARIABLE)
```

In this line:

```
$error = echo 'Captured: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
```

I got this information from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). I just wanted to save the `echo` to a variable. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Comment to the close voter: while the error message is caused by the typo in the first instance, when the commas are replaced with a period there is the further problem of `echo` which doesn't need / want to be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comma is not a concatenation operator in PHP, Period is. Secondly, `echo` doesn't return the string back, it only outputs it. Remove the `echo` and save your string in your variable like this:

```
$error = 'Captured: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
```

Now you may wonder that if this is the case then why do you have an example on PHP.net having comma there?

```
echo 'Captured: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
```

It is because that is not string concatenation, those are  3 different parameters being sent to the `echo` command so in that case it is valid syntax, but for string concatenation it wont be.